# R - google slider by gwidgets

Tags: r, google-visualization, gwidgets

I am looking for a way to implement sometimes like the slider in googleVis' annotated timeline: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline

I can adjust timeframe by both starting and ending points and move the window as well.

gslider only for one slider per track. Would be better to have two or three sliders in one track.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no two (or more) headed slider in gWidgets. One thing you can do is link to sliders together so one is always more than the other though the change handler of each. I do have some tcltk code that implements a double slider if you are interested, but it has some style issues.

Comment: i am temporarily using a combination of gspinbutton and gslider to fit in my purpose but i dun mind trying your double slider.

Answer (score 0):

The `tkexamp` function in the `TeachingDemos` package is one way to create a graph with properties (including data ranges) that can be adjusted using sliders or other GUI tools.